# commands work in linux terminal but not in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, svn, shell

I am trying to run the following shell script using the command:

```
$ bash linuxScript.sh
```

This is what my script looks like

```
#!/bin/bash
svnroot=.../resources
FINDBUGS_HOME="~/opt/findbugs-2.0.1"
svn help
svn export --force ".../resources/GUI.jar"

opt=$1 
case $opt in
     -normal)
    echo "normal mode"
    java -jar %FINDBUGS_HOME%\lib\findbugs.jar -textui -onlyAnalyze common.-,ufm.- -output UFMGUI_Normal.html -html GUI.jar;;
    ...
esac
```

Now for some reason the command `svn help` and `svn export` don't work well (I am calling svn help only to emphasize my point).

They let out the following errors:

```
'unknown command: 'help
Type 'svn help' for usage.
' is not properly URI-encodedaire.com/repos/ufm_ui/branches/UFM_3_7/tools/build/resources/GUI.jar
```

And if I'm already asking it also shouts on non svn related commands:

```
:command not founde 7:
'inuxScript.sh: line 8: syntax error near unexpected token 'in
'inuxScript.sh: line 8: 'case $opt in
```

Now the weird thing is that if I type the svn commands in the terminal everything works fine! I tried to google the solution and I also searched this forum but I couldn't find anything useful.

Help ill be greatly appreciated. Thankyou!

Comment: Is your first positional parameter set? Otherwise `$opt` will be empty

Comment: Try to debug your script by putting `#!/bin/bash -vx` as its first line.

Comment: Add `set -x` after the first line and see what is actually being run.  You have some quoting issue.

Comment: `%FINDBUGS_HOME%\lib\findbugs.jar`? Does it ever make sense in the *nix world? Just wondering.

Comment: Also, check your script for Windows-ish line endings and BOM marks.

Answer (score 1):

1. What is the output of the following command?:

   > ```
   > $ which bash
   > ```

   Does this show "/bin/bash" as you expected?
2. What is the output of the following shell script (assume /tmp/x.sh)?:

   > ```
   > $ cat /tmp/x.sh
   > #!/bin/bash
   > svn help
   >
   > $ bash /tmp/x.sh
   > ```

   It should be "svn help" output.
3. FINDBUGS_HOME looks environment variable and it looks wrongly be referred at
   the following line:

   > ```
   > java -jar %FINDBUGS_HOME%\lib\findbugs.jar ...
   > ```

   Is %FINDBUGS_HOME% right notation?
   (It looks like DOS notation...)
   If it meant shell env-var, isn't it be
   $FINDBUGS_HOME ?

NOTE: $ above is just bash prompt at the same as your post.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$FINDBUGS_HOME`?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your script is saved in DOS format, try open with vim and review file format with

```
:set ff
```

I guess it will give you 'dos'

To convert it to unix format, use

```
:set ff=unix
:w
```

Comment: I had the same problem, tried doing this. It didn't make a difference.